# Green and blue, who are you?

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

> The master of Hero
>   That is charging you
>   Gets his payback
>
> He plays ball Solo
>   After strike two
>   He is now again on Stack
>
> The sun rises so
>   D-Day meets X-? (huh?)

**There is a line that doesn’t fit, what is the number of it?**

Answer (score 3):

*In italic will be my edits in the answer based on @Enigma's comments (thanks !)*

I'm getting the theme but I'm not sure what to make of it. Still, I will say

> The number that doesn't fit is 3.5

Explanation

> There is an obvious Star Wars connection. Each line can be tied to a movie in the story chronological order (except for the the last one, hence the "doesn't fit"):
>  *Well... now I don't know wich one doesn't fit. I'll still say 3.5 since it is missing.*

The master of Hero

> Seems like Obi-Wan Kenobi to me. However, most other lines are directly referencing a movie, this one not, so I'm not quite sure...  Let's say the first (story-wise) appearance of Obi-Wan : **The Phantom Menace**
> *NOPE ! As said @Enigma : Hero is the name of the horse to the comics character Phantom. Still **The Phantom Menace***

That is charging you

> A charge can be an attack => **Attack of the Clones**

Gets his payback

> Payback, revenge, all the same => **Revenge of the Sith**

He plays ball Solo

> Like with Obi-Wan, all I see is a reference to a character (here, Han Solo). And again, I'll go with the first appearance of this character, with **A New Hope**
>  *NOPE AGAIN ! As said @Enigma : Hope Solo is a soccer player, and hints at A New Hope.*

After strike two

> Pretty straightforward => **The Empire Strikes Back**

He is now again on Stack

> "He is now again" is like saying "he is returning" => **Return of the Jedi**

The sun rises so

> When the Sun rises, we awake => **The Force Awakens**. Plus, the Sun rising is a pretty great "force awakening" isn't it ?

D-Day meets X-? (huh?)

> D-Day meets X-Wing ? Definitly **Rogue One**. Or maybe a reference to the last movie (which I didn't see yet, so I may be mistaken). But Rogue One is misplaced here, and should be between the 3rd and 4th episode (or lines). Hence my answer : **3.5** !
>  *WRONG ! As said @Enigma : D-Day is a short for Daniel Day Lewis starring in The Last Mohicans, X-Ray gives the hint of Rey, starring in **The Last Jedi***

Comment: Hero is the name of the horse to the comics character Phantom

Comment: Hope Solo is a soccer player, and hints at A New Hope

Comment: D-Day is a short for Daniel Day Lewis starring in The Last Mohicans, X-Ray gives the hint of Rey, starring in The Last Jedi

Comment: Thank you ! I edited my answer, but still thinking on a better one since I'm not quite sure yet.